# how to get all possible combinations of words in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

We are given N different types of stickers. Each sticker has a lowercase English word on it.

You would like to spell out the given target string by cutting individual letters from your collection of stickers and rearranging them.

You can use each sticker more than once if you want, and you have infinite quantities of each sticker.

What is the minimum number of stickers that you need to spell out the target? If the task is impossible, return -1.

Input:

["with", "example", "science"]
"thehat"
Output:
3
Explanation:

We can use 2 "with" stickers, and 1 "example" sticker.
After cutting and rearrange the letters of those stickers, we can form the target "thehat".
Also, this is the minimum number of stickers necessary to form the target string.

this is my code....

```
class Solution {
public:
    int max(int a ,int b)
    {
        if(a>b){return a;}
        else return b;            
    }
    int minStickers(vector<string>& stickers, string target) 
    {
        int l=target.length();int c2=0;
        int count=0;int c1=0;
        string t1=target;
        string s;
        for(int i=0;i<stickers.size();i++)
        {
            c1=0;
            s=stickers[i];
            for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++)
            {
              count =0;
                for(int k=0;k<target.length();k++)
                {
                    if(s[j]==target[k]){count+=1;target.erase(k,1);k=-1;}
                    cout<<target<<" ";
                }
                if(count>0){c1=max(c1,count);}
            }
             cout<<c1<<" ";

            c2=c2+c1;
        }
        if(target.length()==0){return c2;}
        return -1;
    }
};
```

the first test case works,but this doesnt work...  
["these","guess","about","garden","him"]
  "atomher"
  My output: 4
  Expected: 3

I'm getting number of words but not the minimum number of words....can u help me out

Comment: I dont understand your code (single letter variable names and deep nesting of loops make it difficult to read for me). I have the feeling that you overcomplicated the task. As you can use every sticker as often as you want, you simply have to find a combination of stickers such that the set of all characters from them contains all characters from the target. If you use `std::set` and algorithms it will be much easier

Comment: btw the whole point of the exercise is that you find a solution and make it work. Did you already use a debugger?

Comment: @idclev463035818 ok cool,i'll make it work using a debugger

Comment: What about https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: What is your expected complexity of solution algorithm? What are the constratints?

Comment: If the post is to get the optimal approach, go to discuss section and see the approach https://leetcode.com/problems/stickers-to-spell-word/

Comment: @NikhilSK: Your algorithm choice is wrong (), even if implementation seems right, You are greedy. Suppose stickers `{"h", "hh"}` with target `"hhhh"`, you take 4 time the fist sticker, instead of twice the second.

Comment: @Jarod42 exactly...so how do i check all the words?

Comment: ShridharRKulkarni links gives soms hints. but I don't know the solution.